# Javascript blocking HTML from drawing on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Welcome, i have a problem with drawing on `<canvas>` while the function drawing on said canvas is inside a loop. 

With following code:

```js
do {

    // ... code ...

    // drawing
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    ctx.beginPath();    

    for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        for (let target = 1; target <= 4; target++) {
            if (i + target >= points.length) {
                continue;
            };
            ctx.moveTo(points[i][0], points[i][1]);
            ctx.lineTo(points[i+target][0], points[i+target][1]);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

    do {
        var tEnd = performance.now();
        sleep(10);
    } while (tEnd - tStart < 25);

} while (1);
```

In this example, code doesn't work only due to the `do-while(1)`, when using `do-while(0)`, code runs once, and works properly. I know the problem is Javascript not letting HTML change anything, but i don't know how to fix this problem.

**note: There is a similar question to this one, it didn't resolve my problem**, 
Cheers

Comment: Don't use a `do...while` loop unless your while condition breaks the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced `while(1)` with a function definition:

```js
function foo() {

 //code

}
```

At the end of function I'm calling `setTimeout(foo, 50)`. This fixes the issue:

```js
function foo() {

 //code

 setTimeout(foo, 50)
}
```

Using this, the function loops every iteration +50ms. By measuring the time used by the function, i can normalize the function's fps across multiple computers, and set the timeout to be as low as humanly possible.